# Ubuntu 18.04.3 Server Edition Installation failing

Tags: 18.04, server, system-installation, software-installation, lvm

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.3 Server Edition previously downloaded from 64-bit PC (AMD64) server install image: cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.3/release/ubuntu-18.04.3-server-amd64.iso,
and put as ISO image to an USB :"Installation is complete.  You may now run Ubuntu on other computers by booting them with this drive inserted".

I'm getting this error : "Select and install software step failed":  https://drive.google.com/open?id=14Ce1yJz-0kPuWrDU6dBNEnqF231_dahl

These are the logs files I got from a temporary local webserver set by Ubuntu 18.04.3 Server installation:
HardwareSummary: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CTLOaSb4l2byhvGeCyrK2C00xWveTfW3

MediaInfo: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AE01HnJ7uRrdNcNkotYZevBNdtzVhemV

Partman: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GyZZlVtvtvRFZ35WBY0bS52bCcwBDd8d

syslog: https://drive.google.com/open?id=14_-OKmcJLP82-KfHEiqCOJoCKsZ_rEnP

And this the current LVM configuration:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wYjVuiVrXbkDCyH0i7DAOIAre-Tzw-qf

How to solve the problem and correctly proceed to the Ubuntu 18.04.3 Server Edition installation?
Looking forward to your kind help.
Marco

Comment: How did you set up your LVM configuration? It contains an “unknown device” which is clearly a mistake. Your syslog is full of filesystem errors that are caused by this probably. And please [upload the images to stack.imgur.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) so they can be embedded.

Comment: @Melebius you were right! During my attempts to install Ubuntu I made some mess with the LVM configuration. Now, after deleting the previous partitions, everything went fine